# extjs date dateFormat in model seems not work

Tags: extjs

Extjs 5, I use JsonpProxy, when store sync(), browser will send data like

```
_dc         1414743789200
callback    Ext.data.JsonP.callback2
records     {"empid":8047,"empname":"Tom","action":1,"typeid":1,"num":1,"spec":170,"oper_id":5234,"actiontime":"2014-10-31T16:23:07","id":"jx.model.Item-1"}
type        1
```

The actiontime format includes a 'T' I don't want and I want to change `actiontime` format in `records` like "20141031". Whatever I set dateFormt of actiontime in Model. `records` remains the same.

Store is:

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.store.Item', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  ....
   proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        api: {
            read: '',
            create: 'http://192.168.202.6:8080/jx/PutAppJson.action',
            update: '',
            destroy: ''
        },
        extraParams: 
        {
            type: '1'
        },
        url: 'defualt.action',
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
```

Model is

```
        {
            type: 'date',
            name: 'actiontime',
            dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
            dateReadFormat: 'Y-m-d',
            dateWriteFormat: 'Y-m-d'
        }
```

Grid is

```
      {
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            width: 200,
            dataIndex: 'actiontime',
            text: 'WorkTime',
            format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
        }
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that parsing `2014-10-31T16:23:07` using `Y-m-d` does not work. It should work, however, if you use `dateFormat:'c'` on the model.

Comment: Still `2014-10-31T16:23:07`.